# How to get next and previous value in a 2D array (row major order) in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on two functions which take in a 2d array and a current row and column value. It should return the next value or the previous value (if there is one) and if there isn't it should return (-1,-1)

In the functions, I call the value (number) the node and nodeSolution is the 2d array.

My problem is that I keep getting errors in my use function when I use this to backtrack. I have been bug fixing but I cannot seem to find where my code is going wrong. I'm getting a lot of index out of range, etc.

```
def nextNode(row, col, nodeSolution):
    if(row == len(nodeSolution) and col == len(nodeSolution)):
        return (-1,-1)
    if(col == len(nodeSolution) - 1):
        return (row+1, 0)
    return (row, col+1)

def previousNode(row, col, nodeSolution):
    if(row == 0 and col == 0):
        return (-1,-1)
    if(col == 0):
        return (row-1, len(nodeSolution) - 1)
    return (row, col-1)
```

Both functions should always return a row, col value that is in the 2d array or (-1,-1)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this an `n` by `n` matrix, e.g. a perfect square?